# Why my navbar using Bootstrap is not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bui.css"

    <!-- Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">About <span class="sr-only"> </span> </a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Porfolio</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>   
    <!-- JS -->
 <script> src = "bootstrap.min.js"</script>
 <script> src = "popper.min"</script>
 <script> src = "jquery-3.3.1.slim.min"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use Bootstrap by download instead of using cdn but it didn't worked. It appeared liked this  https://codepen.io/buiquanganh2001/pen/KKKNyrP

[image]

Comment: jquery should be loaded BEFORE bootstrap

Comment: The correct sequence for loading Bootstrap js files is 1) jQuery 2) popper 3) bootstrap _ visit the specific Bootstrap page for more information >>> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: order of file is affected as well ? , thank you.

Comment: the order is logical when you think about it _ jQuery is required to run both popper and bootstrap and bootstrap wouldn't work correctly without popper ; )

Answer (score 0):

after few hours , I have figured it out you have to link it in a specific folder for example `href=foldername/file.css`